# why boolean not work on solidfy modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have a normal plane and a cube. I have given little thickness to the plane. and i want just cut a hole in that plane. I have to model in the file.
to my right hand what i want to achieve. The problem is that with the normal boolean tool its not working. I have install the booltron addon and go the result. to the left hand is the sample to experiment. I have acheive what i want to from booltron but the problem is that the solidfy modifier apply automatically with that. Is there any option or other way i can cut the hole in that plane without apply the solidify modifier.  [image] blend file here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZT1FxOTdoX0drQVk

boolean did not work with the steps [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the Plane
2. Add a boolean modifier.
3. Set the **Object** property to the *Cube*.
4. Set the **Operation** property to *Difference*.

[image: boolean modifier]

Comment: thanks for replying me With your steps mention above i have done same it did not work. As u can see my .gif image above it did not cut the hole into the plane and 1 more thing i notice above in your red mark image below the object cube u have another BMesh i do not have in my blender.

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.78. Which version are you using? Try updating in case the boolean modifier is improved in later versions.

Comment: 2.77 a i have installed the new version 2.78 but it clash after few 2-3 min dont know whats the problem. i have email to the company but still no response so i uninstall and install again 2.77a